# When changed state of a multiple nested array of objects in React get error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, nested

When I try to modify the configuration state, namely a nested array into an array, an error occurs 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')'. Specifically, I'm trying to add an element to an array with the following code:

```
const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0);
const [configure, setConfigure] = useState(config);

const addField = (name: string, value: any, type: string) => {
  const newItem = {
    _id: uuidv4(),
    name,
    value,
    type
  }
  const newArr = [...configure.sections[tabValue].fields, newItem]

  setConfigure((prevState: any) => ({
    ...prevState.sections[tabValue],
    fields: newArr
  }));

  console.log(configure)
}
```

Where tabValue is the configuration section.The code below renders each of the sections, specifically in this block of code an error occurs after adding an element:

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchForm handleUpdateSearch={handleUpdateSearch} />
      <CreateForm
        onAdd={addField} />
      <TabList
        tabValue={tabValue}
        setTabValue={setTabValue}
        configure={configure}
        setConfigure={setConfigure}
      />
      {configure.sections.map((s: any, i: any) => {
        return (
          <>
            {tabValue === i && <Section
              {...s}
              configure={configure}
              setConfigure={setConfigure}
              tabValue={tabValue}
            />}
          </>
        )
      })}

    </div>
  );
```

How to solve a problem? I believe that the snag is in the incorrect expansion of the state change function when adding an element.
[The configuration object looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUzcL.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see is in setConfigure, below is the code you can give it a try

```
const [tabValue, setTabValue] = useState(0);
const [configure, setConfigure] = useState(config);

const addField = (name: string, value: any, type: string) => {
  const newItem = {
    _id: uuidv4(),
    name,
    value,
    type
  }
  const newArr = [...configure.sections[tabValue].fields, newItem]

  setConfigure((prevState: any) => {
    const newState = {...prevState};
    newState.sections[tabValue] = newArr;
    return newState
  });

  console.log(configure)
}
```

Some time nested update becomes cumbersome then you can give [immerjs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) a try

Comment: Hey! Got the following error after using your code : Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'